# access asp.net core service from docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting started with development of containerized applications and ASP.Net Core 2.0. Both these areas are fairly new to me and I'm just trying to set up a simple proof of concept application isn't panning out at I hoped.

At the moment I have 2 separate WebApi services running in Docker containers (Linux container running on Windows 10).
To start with, I just created them using:

`dotnet new webapi`

I then added a for each of them `Dockerfile` that looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

I also created a `docker-compose.yml` that looks like this:

```
version: "3"
    services:
        service1:
            build: ./service1
            ports:
                - "8000:80"
        service2:
            build: ./service2
            ports:
                - "8001:80"
```

using `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` I can get up an running. Accessing the services from the host machine is working without any flaw.

The goal of this proof of concept application is however, to these services connected. Basically that `service1` is accessing `service2` to get additional data.

I added a method to `service1` that attempts to access data from `service2`:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://service2");
        var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/values/5");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw in not success

        var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return stringResponse;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        return $"error: '{e.Message}'";
    }
}
```

this fails with the following message:

> error: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).'

I confirmed that the `service2` name can be resolved within `service1`. Pinging service1 is also successful.

Adding

```
depends_on:
    - "service2"
```

to the `Docker-compose.yml` doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Am I missing a some additional configuration to be able to access the other service from within a docker container?

Any help or hint are appreciated.

Thanks,
Jörg

Comment: If I see this correctly, a 503 is issued by the server. So your server is reachable, but some problem prevents it from responding as you would like, Are there any logs?

Comment: On closer inspection, your build could be the problem. Could you try a standard build? (e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/blob/master/aspnetapp/Dockerfile)

Comment: Changing the build doesn't make a difference. I'm still seeing the same behaviour. I don't think there are any logs. Is there any additional logging that can be enabled?

Comment: this error might not be coming from service2 after all. I stopped the container that runs service2 and the response that I get in service1 is still the same. This might be a networking issue.

Comment: can you confirm that you can ping service2 from service 1 (docker exec -it <containerId> /bin/bash and then ping the server name?

Comment: I can confirm that ping is working fine. I found that it is actually a proxy problem. In order to be able to pull public images and build, I need to set a proxy. This proxy apparently also gets set when the image gets build. Attempting to use `curl http://google.com` is working fine. the response of `curl http://service2/api/values` is actually a response from the proxy used by the host machine. Once the http proxy has been removed from the environment variables the curl command for service2 starts working and google.com stops working. Now I just need to get service1 to ignore the proxy.

Comment: I added `ENV HTTP_PROXY=""` to the Dockerfile for service1 and now it's working as expected. I'm not quite happy with this approach, but it will do for now.